# How to make html page zoomable only to some extent in any browser?

Tags: php, html, css, meta

I have search it on google but it gives the result of disable zoom feature completely, but I want to do it to some extent.

I want that user can not zoom over 200%. Like in chrome browser, we can zoom the page to 500%, but I want to set it at max 200%.

I want this as when I zoom in my web page then its alignment get distorted,so tell me any method to solve this issue.

Comment: You can't really do this. Even those solutions, that claim to disable zoom entirely, are in fact easy to work around.

Answer (score 0):

I think, better way is zoom by using HTML and CSS. Please note that php is server side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't do this why you not use CSS? CSS can do this ..
Already answered here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18536411/4977543

Comment: body {
    zoom: 2;
}
This will zoom the page to 200%. But I want that user can not zoom over 200%. Like in chrome browser, we can zoom the page to 500%, but i want to set it at max 200%.