# Twitter Bootstrap Fixed Grid To Resoinsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developed a site using twitter bootstrap(2.3.2) fixed grid system. This is 960px website. I am not added responsive code in bootstrap.css file. But now i want to responsive it not fluid. I already download responsive code from http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html site and past that code in a responsive.css file.When i add this file to my website it become 1170px.but i don't want this.i want my website default value 960px but in tablet and mobile it must responsive view.How can i do this?Please help me i am new in bootstrap.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before downloading the customized code from http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html untick the 'Large desktops (>1200px)' option below the Responsive title.

I'm just guessing but that ought do it because it doesn't generate the CSS on the responsive file for over 979px then.

Comment: Ehm, sorry? What do you mean?

Comment: @media (min-width: 980px) , media (max-width: 979px) ,media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) , media (max-width: 480px) , media (max-width: 767px) , media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)   Only this midea are available. I am using fixed grid system so i need to add more mdeia for other device size. Is it right way to achieve responsive website using fixed grid  ?

Answer (score 1):

**create your own less file as a main less file ( like bootstrap.less ).**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730263/setting-max-width-for-body-using-bootstrap) is a link to a similar question answered very correctly.

Accordingly any property of bootstrap you can overwrite as per you wish.

Cheers!!!